# While uploading multiple files the browse button is not showing using jquery and Asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have Tried to implement multiple file upload like gmail in button click using uplodify jquery plugin but after page loading i ma not getting any button
My coding i am mentioning below![The below is the designing andnext one is coding in ashx page![][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76zV8.png)

if you have idea why the select files button not coming please respond to me thanks
In advance

Comment: Please post your source code here instead of posting a screenshot.

Comment: Why do you use jquery? You could do it easily with HTML5: `<input type="file" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" name="FileUpload1" id="FileUpload1" />` or if you using .NET 4.5 you could use `<asp:FileUpload ID="uploadFileButton" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server"/>`

Comment: Thanks for reply But my requirement is like Gmail file Upload Multiple files Should be uploaded if it is possible please suggest me thank you.

Comment: what do you mean with "like Gmail"? Do you want that as soon as you click the "OK" button your files are uploaded?

Comment: yes exactly as soon as attach and  close with progress bars only attach but should be visible